# C# Oracle Connection with MSDAORA.1

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net, oledb

I have a Excel-Sheet connected with a Oracle Database with MSDAORA.

Connection String in Excel is

```
Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Data Source=yyy.com
```

CommandType is `Tabledirect` and CommandText is `"zzzzzz"."ZZZZZZZZ"`

Integrated Security is `Windows Authentication`

So i createt a small Test App for connecting me to the Oracle-DB with C#.
It seems the Connection String is the same, but its not working.

> Error Message : OLEDB Exception - Error executing OLEDB Procedur

Using VS2012 / NET3.5 /

```
tbConnectionString.Text = @"Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Data Source=yyy.com";
tbCommandText.Text = @"""zzzzzzz"".""ZZZZZZZZZZ""";
myOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(tbConnectionString.Text);
OleDbCommand myOleDbCommand = myOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();
myOleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
myOleDbCommand.CommandText = tbCommandText.Text;
myOleDbConnection.Open();
```

THX

Answer (score 0):

Is an issue of Operating system and VS version. 
Because I faced same problem before when using Win 7.

After diagnosing the issue , we find solution of Oracle.DataAccess.

Check out the support of msdaora.1.

Comment: I have seen the Oracle.DataAccess but when im using the Oracle Components should i install this on the Target Machines ?

Comment: Oracle component contain different packages.. You can install ODAC 11g Data Provider for visual studio.. which helps you for connection